# How Can I run a Command after another Command in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have many Command class and they are running in background in my Laravel project.
I have a scenario and I want to run one of the after another one.

```
        $schedule->command('mycommand:first')->cron("*/40 * * * *")->withoutOverlapping();
        $schedule->command('mycommand:two')->cron("*/40 * * * *")->withoutOverlapping();
```

they are running every 40 minutes. but I want to run Command two 10 minutes after Command first.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to start command 10 minutes after the first command, you have to set properly cron command. So for your example it would be:

```
    $schedule->command('mycommand:first')->cron("*/40 * * * *")->withoutOverlapping();
    $schedule->command('mycommand:two')->cron("*/50 * * * *")->withoutOverlapping();
```

If you want to learn more about those cron settings you can try something like [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/)

If you want to run `mycommand:two` 10 minutes after `mycommand:first` finished, you have to probably edit `mycommand:first` to set some timeout and execution of `mycommand:second` at the end of the command.